# Automatic tagging (based on other tags)

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I have the following taxonomies:

- Countries
- Cities

When I create a new node Im allowing to enter "Cities" as a field of that node. Given that I have a "mapping" in place, how can I automatically assign the "Country" to that node as well (the user doesn`t have to do it, it happens in the background)?

Example:
I "tag" a node with "New York" - and that node is atomatically tagged with "United States" behind the scenes. When listing "United States" in a view, the node tagged "New York" would appear amond all other nodes tagged with US cities.

Also, where would the mapping of "New York -> United States" be defined?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Anyone got a clue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the module to do it:

[Hierarchical Term Reference Autocomplete](https://www.drupal.org/project/term_ref_autocomplete)

I think it's preview image shows exactly what you want

[image]